# Creating directories problem

Tags: java

Can't figure out why this keeps creating 2 folders? It makes a '0' folder and whatever the jobID is from the html. I want uploaded files in the jobID folder, not the '0' folder.

```
        int userID = 1; // test
        String coverLetter = "";
        String status = "Review";
        int jobID = 0;
        String directoryName = "";

        boolean isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);
        if(isMultipart && request.getContentType() != null)
        {
            // Create a factory for disk-based file items
            FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();

            // Create a new file upload handler
            ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);

            // Parse the request
            List /* FileItem */ items = null;
            try
            {
                items = upload.parseRequest(request);
            }
            catch(FileUploadException e) {}

            // Process the uploaded items
            Iterator iter = items.iterator();

            while(iter.hasNext())
            {
                FileItem item = (FileItem)iter.next();

                if(item.isFormField())
                {
                    if(item.getFieldName().equals("coverLetter"))
                        coverLetter = item.getString();
                    if(item.getFieldName().equals("jobID"))
                        jobID = Integer.parseInt(item.getString()); 
                }

                directoryName = request.getRealPath("/") + "/Uploads/CV/" + jobID + "/";    

                File theDir = new File(directoryName);
                if (!theDir.exists())
                    theDir.mkdir();

                if(item.getFieldName().equals("file"))
                {   
                    File uploadedFile = new File(directoryName + item.getName());
                    try
                    {
                        item.write(uploadedFile);
                    }
                    catch(Exception e) {}
                }
}
```

Edit:

Problem solved.I want uploaded files

It was because it was in the jobID folder, not the '0' folder.

Comment: The program flow looks suspect. You are instantiating job id to be '0' and setting it to a value if item.isFormField is true. Is your program flow going inside the if block. May be it never gets in to isformfield = true block.

Comment: If you answer your own problem, do it as an answer instead of editing the original question. StackOverflow would be an awful resource if everyone did this.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this isn't true:

`item.getFieldName().equals("jobID")`

It's a bit difficult to guess though. Have you tried debugging in Eclipse (or similar)? Adding some logging might help too.

Comment: It does validate - I did system.out.println and I got 2 values. :S

Comment: Is it true on both occasions? What size is items?

Comment: Items is more than 1 as i've just found, it's looping through my forms.. and there's 2 forms

Answer (score 1):

There must be 2 items parsed from the request, So perhaps you are sending 2 upload items.

The first item doesn't have the jobID FieldName so the directory name remain

```
.../Uploads/CV/0
```

So thats the time which is causing problems.

The second item does have the job ID so the directory gets created correctly.

Can you post the form so we can see, it may be something on there. Is the cover letter an additional file without jobId?

You could solve it by only creating dir if jobID exists.

Answer (score 0):

Try printing/logging the `jobID` before the below line:

`directoryName = request.getRealPath("/") + "/Uploads/CV/" + jobID + "/";`